# How to query interval without including the current date?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE status != 'done' 
AND added >= (NOW() - interval '30 days') order by added desc;
```

However, it includes the current date. How do I query without including results from the current date?

Comment: Postgres or MySQL? Please do not add tags for databases not involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I query without including results from the current date?

Just exclude the current date by applying a `<` condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE status <> 'done' 
  AND added >= (NOW() - interval '30 days') 
  AND added < current_date
order by added desc;
```